# GA4 API how to obtain number of itemListPosition for a product

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am migrating some code from UA to GA4 and I am having troubles migrating a query.

I have a query to UA API that given a product id, i can retrieve for each day and for each position the product appeared on a list how many times it appeared, this is the query I had and works correcly:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3AXXXXXX&dimensions=ga%3Adate%2Cga%3AproductListPosition&metrics=ga%3AproductListClicks%2Cga%3AproductListViews&filters=ga%3AproductSku%3D%3DP-2375&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=yesterday
```

No, I am unable to replicate this in GA4. This is the parameters I an trying to send:

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "date"
    },
    {
      "name": "itemListPosition"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "itemListViewEvents"
    }
  ],
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "2023-05-20",
      "endDate": "2023-05-26"
    }
  ]
}
```

But in GA4 Query explorer I get the following error:

> Please remove itemListClickEvents to make the request compatible. The
> request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see
> https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

Which metrics/dimensions should I use?